# Resolving URI character encoding issues in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, character-encoding, uri

I'm working with a Ruby on Rails application that makes a client side API call to a 3rd party service. It then takes strings from the 3rd party API and generates URIs with them.

Unfortunately, Rails fails to parse some of the URIs due to encoding errors. I have tried running the strings through encodeURIComponent, but this does not resolve the issue.

Here is the error I get:

```
Processing ApplicationController#index (for 67.101.113.66 at 2010-08-12 23:24:55) [GET]
  Parameters: {"name"=>"Camilo Andr\xE9s \xD1ustes", "recipient_id"=>"279"}

ArgumentError (invalid byte sequence in US-ASCII):
  <internal:prelude>:8:in `synchronize'
  /home/heroku_rack/lib/static_assets.rb:9:in `call'
  /home/heroku_rack/lib/last_access.rb:25:in `call'
  /home/heroku_rack/lib/date_header.rb:14:in `call'
  thin (1.2.6) lib/thin/connection.rb:76:in `block in pre_process'
  thin (1.2.6) lib/thin/connection.rb:74:in `catch'
  thin (1.2.6) lib/thin/connection.rb:74:in `pre_process'
  thin (1.2.6) lib/thin/connection.rb:57:in `process'
  thin (1.2.6) lib/thin/connection.rb:42:in `receive_data'
  eventmachine (0.12.10) lib/eventmachine.rb:256:in `run_machine'
  eventmachine (0.12.10) lib/eventmachine.rb:256:in `run'
  thin (1.2.6) lib/thin/backends/base.rb:57:in `start'
  thin (1.2.6) lib/thin/server.rb:156:in `start'
  thin (1.2.6) lib/thin/controllers/controller.rb:80:in `start'
  thin (1.2.6) lib/thin/runner.rb:177:in `run_command'
  thin (1.2.6) lib/thin/runner.rb:143:in `run!'
  thin (1.2.6) bin/thin:6:in `<top (required)>'
  /usr/ruby1.9.1/bin/thin:19:in `load'

  /usr/ruby1.9.1/bin/thin:19:in `<main>'
```

How do I properly handle these strings as input for my application?

Answer (score 1):

This works for me: `<%= u name -%>`

I use this technique everytime i have to pass on auth token around in my views:
 `<%= u form_authenticity_token %>`

Since the above is for views, if you want ruby specific:

```
require 'uri'
foo = "http://google.com?query=hello"

bad = URI.escape(foo)
good = URI.escape(foo, Regexp.new("[^#{URI::PATTERN::UNRESERVED}]"))

bad_uri = "http://mysite.com?service=#{bad}&bar=blah"
good_uri = "http://mysite.com?service=#{good}&bar=blah"

puts bad_uri
# outputs "http://mysite.com?service=http://google.com?query=hello&bar=blah"

puts good_uri
# outputs "http://mysite.com?service=http%3A%2F%2Fgoogle.com%3Fquery%3Dhello&bar=blah"
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks. If this is the solution, however, I need to do it in javascript.

The name comes from a jsonp api call, and then is appended to the url.

My solution for now was to switch the application to use Ruby 1.8 instead of 1.9.

Comment: Even if it comes from a jsonp api call i am guessing you are receiving it in the controller's action as `params[:name]`, `params[:recepient_id]` right? Why not just do `URI.escape(params[:name], Regexp.new("[^#{URI::PATTERN::UNRESERVED}]"))`? I see from the log output that you are receiving the parameters.. Just escape it before storing/manipulating the data. If you could provide a skinny version of your controller's action it would be more easier to provide a solution.

Comment: It's a jsonp api call that's all done client side. The data is then sent to a rails controller. It fails inside of Rack before it even hits the controller action.